# B1/B2 category US visa

Tags: b1-b2-visas, us-visa, conferences

I am after some advice here regarding the B1/B2 category US visa. I live in London and I applied for the visa to attend a conference that was in October 2022 but I could not attend it because of the delay in the appointment (January 2023 was the earliest I could book). Do you know if I can use this scheduled appointment to apply for a new visa (new DS-160) for another conference?
I have written to the US embassy in London but have not heard anything yet.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Bring your invitation and itinerary to the interview, you don't need to submit a new application.

Comment: many thanks for your answer. Are you saying it based on your personal experiences? Just asking this as I could not find any information on the US embassy website. Thank you again.

Comment: @Dev yes. Plans change, especially with such a long lead time. You get a visa to enter the country, not to enter a specific conference.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Much appreciated!